# Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure on Communication Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, communication-site

I am working with SharePoint Online.

It turns out the Communication Site has just the template I am looking for, with no left-side navigation and search box in the top right corner.

However, It does not allow me to activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure :(

So I need one of these solutions:

1. How to use Communication Site Master Page in a Team Site
2. How to activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure Communication Site

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The new templates (Communication Site and Team Site) does not have master pages like in classic SharePoint sites have, so this is not possible.
2. You can't activate these features on Communication Sites, however you can do it on the Team Sites...

---

If you really want to work with a classic view of SharePoint, you could either stick to a Team Site template and modify it using CSS to hide the navigation, or you could create a site using one of the old templates.

My recommendation however would be to get comfortable with the new look & feel and try to build your solutions using that.